# How do I create an image from a Base64-encoded string in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, base64

A web service echoes a Base64 encoded image as a string. How can one decode and display this encoded image in a Swift project?

Specifically, I would like to take an image, which is already provided by the web service as a string in Base64 format, and understand how to display it in a UIImageView.

The articles I have found thus far describe deprecated techniques or are written in Objective-C, which I am not familiar with. How do you take in a Base64-encoded string and convert it to a UIImage?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Turn your base64 encoded string into an `NSData` instance by doing something like this:

```
let encodedImageData = ... get string from your web service ...
let imageData = NSData(base64EncodedString: encodedImageData options: .allZeros)
```

Then turn the imageData into a UIImage:

```
let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
```

You can then set the image on a `UIImageView` for example:

```
imageView.image = image
```

Comment: In Swift 2. let imageData = NSData(base64EncodedString: encodedImageData options: [])

Comment: The comma between the parameters of NSData is missing.

Comment: In Swift 3/4, it's `Data(base64Encoded: encodedImageData)`

Answer (score 3):

To decode Base64 encoded string to image, you can use the following code in Swift:

```
let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.fromRaw(0)!)
var decodedimage = UIImage(data: decodedData)
println(decodedimage)
yourImageView.image = decodedimage as UIImage
```

Even better, you can check if `decodedimage` is `nil` or not before assigning to image view.

Comment: This is not wokring.. decodedimage always nil